# Does the participant-to-participant secret share in FROST distributed key generation need to remain confidential?

Tags: secret-sharing, threshold-cryptography

In its application of Shamir secret sharing, the [FROST paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/852.pdf) in Figure 1 Round 2 Step 1 requires each participant $P_i$ to *securely* send to each other participant $P_\ell$ a secret share $(\ell, f_i(\ell))$.

I wonder what *securely* means in this context. I assume at least the Security Assumptions from §4 (Message Validation, Reliable Message Delivery, Participant Identification). But does it also require message confidentiality? What could happen if attackers learn $f_i(\ell)$?

My use case is $t=n=2$ distributed key generation in which the $f_i(\ell)$ are recorded on a public trusted file. This way both participants only need to keep their initial randomness (Round 1 Step 1) locally available and confidential, while remaining able to reproduce their long-lived private signing share (Round 2 Step 3) on demand. In my use case, this initial randomness is easier to protect since I can use long-term TEE/SE/HSM-generated keys instead of needing to protect keys produced using other I/O.

Comment: If the participants know each other, could you generate an encryption key for them? HSMs should support some form of KEM or IES. Storing the encrypted $f_i(l)$ lets you side-step the issue.

Comment: Thanks Aman! If indeed the $f_i(\ell)$ shares need to remain confidential, I’ll look at the mentioned TEE/SE/HSM indeed for additional encryption. I just hoped to learn a proof that the shares could be left out in plaintext.